# Financial statement and stock market data

Tags: data, market-data, finance, historical-data, accounting

How is it possible to have access to Datastream, Bloomberg, Wrds database? Is there another free database with long historical data? In fact, I need long time series data belonging to NYSE and NASADAQ companies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try finance.yahoo for example http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG+Historical+Prices it is free, for the other ones you mentioned you have to pay, usually a lot.